# test error message in python 3

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, exception

I have the following test method

```
def test_fingerprintBadFormat(self):
    """
    A C{BadFingerPrintFormat} error is raised when unsupported
    formats are requested.
    """
    with self.assertRaises(keys.BadFingerPrintFormat) as em:
        keys.Key(self.rsaObj).fingerprint('sha256-base')
    self.assertEqual('Unsupported fingerprint format: sha256-base',
        em.exception.message)
```

Here is the exception class.

```
class BadFingerPrintFormat(Exception):
    """
    Raises when unsupported fingerprint formats are presented to fingerprint.
    """
```

this test method works perfectly fine in Python2 but fails in python 3 with the following message

```
builtins.AttributeError: 'BadFingerPrintFormat' object has no attribute 'message'
```

How can I test the error message in Python3. I don't like the idea of using `asserRaisesRegex` as it tests the regex rather than the exception message.

Comment: Can you shed some light on BadFingerPrintFormat?

Comment: @LajosArpad I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.message` attribute was removed from exceptions in Python 3. Use `.args[0]` instead:

```
self.assertEqual('Unsupported fingerprint format: sha256-base',
    em.exception.args[0])
```

or use `str(em.exception)` to get the same value:

```
self.assertEqual('Unsupported fingerprint format: sha256-base',
    str(em.exception))
```

This will work both on Python 2 and 3:

```
>>> class BadFingerPrintFormat(Exception):
...     """
...     Raises when unsupported fingerprint formats are presented to fingerprint.
...     """
...
>>> exception = BadFingerPrintFormat('Unsupported fingerprint format: sha256-base')
>>> exception.args
('Unsupported fingerprint format: sha256-base',)
>>> exception.args[0]
'Unsupported fingerprint format: sha256-base'
>>> str(exception)
'Unsupported fingerprint format: sha256-base'
```